# How to convert from Magicavoxel to Blender to Unity, without losing the texture/colors

Tags: animation, uv, unity, color

I'm trying to make an animated model, and I make the model in magicavoxel, then animate it in blender, then put it in my unity game, but when I put it in my unity game, it shows only white, that's it. Help? Any file type is ok, except obj. I have been looking for the answer all day btw, so I've done research on it, but none of the solutions work.

Comment: Did you check Unity docs? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-ImportObjectBlender.html

Answer (score 2):

If just import the OBJ file(exported from MagicaVoxel) into Blender, animated it and want to sent it to Unity with textures I think this will help you:

**On Blender**

- Export the model as FBX

**On Unity**

- Import the FBX
- Import the voxel PNG(palete) file into Unity as a texture
- Drag the FBX file to the Scene
- Create a new Material
- Associate the new material to the model on Scene
- Drag the PNG(palete) image to the ALBEDO field of the material

**Another solution would be this:** If you export an OBJ from MagicaVoxel and want to send it to Unity with the textures/colors you have to send to Unity all the 3 files MagicaVoxel generates when you export an OBJ file (.obj, .png, .mtl)

- On the file explorer you have to select all these 3 files and drag-and-drop them all at once into a unity folder inside the Asset folder (need to drag from file explorer and drop into Unity software interface). This way Unity will receive the 3D Object model, the texture and the info about how the texture will be used into the 3D model.

Well, about that and a lot more you will find on this MagicaVoxel/Blender/Unity course: 
[Modelagem 3D com MagicaVoxel para criação de games em Unity](https://www.udemy.com/magicavoxel-curso-completo-interatividade-unity3d/?couponCode=VOLTA_AS_AULAS2018)